# Importing global functions in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I'm working on Drupal 8 theme and I have some problems with file imports.

I need to create a functions file to declare global functions and later import it  in different modules.

I have read that mytheme.theme do the trick for this issue.

But I'm placing a function at `themes/custom/mytheme/mytheme.theme` and im not able to call it from, for example, `modules/custom/mytheme_mymodule/src/Controller/ControllerFile.php`

I don't know if it is related to namespace's issues or what else could it be.

Thanks in advance.